# every time Software Updater installs something new，ethernet adapter goes wrong

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, ethernet, realtek

After Software Updater installed something,my network didn't work.it seemed that ethernet adapter driver was updated and the new driver didn't work on my computer.so i have to install the old one every time after the Software Updater run.what should i do to stop Software Updater installing new  ethernet adapter driver but still update others? PS:the model of ethernet adapter is Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411. and the version of Ubuntu is ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

You face this problem, because you probably compiled r8168 driver from source and blacklisted r8169 kernel driver that is supposed to manage this device.

This a working but a wrong way to install drivers in Ubuntu. You will have to re-install the driver after each kernel upgrade.

It is true that some revisions of r8168 chips work not perfectly with default kernel driver, but it is getting improvements.

If you build a kernel module from source, after each kernel upgrade it does not work. This is normal.

I can suggest first of all test if the default kernel driver works OK.
You need to look in files located at `/etc/modprobe.d/` for line

```
blacklist r8169
```

Remove this line using `sudo gedit -H  and save the file.
Or remove the whole file if it is the only string there by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/<file_name>
```

Reboot and test your network.

If you still have issues, then you can always install `r8168-dkms` package from Ubuntu repository by running

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

This module will rebuild after kernel upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall r8168-dkms time to time after updates, because it was working but "not so good" - noticeable delays even in VNC conenction, low iperf results when checked..
After reinstalling compiled dkms and blacklisted r8169, gigabit link mean gigabit iperf result, no delays, no problem at all.

That was Asrock Baitrail J1900 onboard realtek, but another in pci-e port, and even dual lan..  all cards I had here were the same realtek 8169 chip.. All in troubles with default driver.
And "some" of them (tp-link I guess), seemed to have reversed link detaction - driver think the cable is unplugged when link is on, and vice versa..

Recently I moved to Asrock Broadwell N3050M board, where (what a surprise) was realtek 8169 onboard as well.. 
But this time, I had to upgrade kernel (I guess), and went to lts-vivid with 3.19 kernel, where old dkms refused to install.

But realtek has newer dkms driver right on their web and it works. Version: 8.040.00-NAPI